# Repeat a Function when it meets the condition

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loops, actionscript, air

I have a question about action script 3.

I am making a game, the basic rule of the game is:

1. an object falls from the top
2. the hero(user) has to avoid the object
3. if the object hits the ground or the hero: the hero dies or the object falls again from the top.

I am using the add child method for the object, and timer function for the fall.

the problem is:
when the object hits the ground, the function does not loop. it ends just like that.  so there wont be any falling objects anymore.

please help me. thanks :)

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, addfire1);

function addfire1(e:Event):void
{
    if (api1==false)//if object is not on the stage
    {
        randomx = randomRange();//generate random X
        addChild(api);
        api.x = randomx;//set x
        api1 = true;//object is now on stage
    }
    if (api.hitTestObject(hero) || api.hitTestObject(ground))
    {
        falltimer.stop();
        //stop timer;
        falltimer.reset();
        //reset fall Count to zero ;
        removeChild(api);//object removed
        api1=false;
    }
}

function firefall(Event:TimerEvent):void
{
    if (api1)
    {
        api.y +=  20;//set speed y
    }
}
```

Comment: Why bother removing/adding the object each time it hits the floor? Just move the same object back up to the top: `api.y = 0;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just separate the two cases: hero and floor.

```
if (api.hitTestObject(hero))
{
    falltimer.stop();
    //stop timer;
    falltimer.reset();
    //reset fall Count to zero ;
    removeChild(api);//object removed
    api1=false;
} 
else if (api.hitTestObject(ground))
{
   //reset object's position
   api.y = -20;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is only one object falling at the time I'd not remove the object but instead just move it to the original y position and a new x position. And instead of having the timer i'd create an update-function that runs every time you enter a frame.

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);

private function update(e:Event):void
{
    if(!api1) //if object is not on the stage (same as api1==false)
    {
        addfire1();
    }

    if(api1) //if object if on stage (same as api1==true)
    {
        firefall();
    }
}

private function addfire1(e:Event):void
{
    randomx = randomRange();//generate random X
    addChild(api);
    api.x = randomx;//set x
    api1 = true;//object is now on stage

    if (api.hitTestObject(hero))
    {
        hitHero(); //execute what should happen to the hero when the he is hit
        resetFire();
    }
    else if(api.hitTestObject(ground))
    {
        resetFire();
    }
}

private function firefall(Event:TimerEvent):void
{
    api.y +=  20;//set speed y
}

private function resetFire():void
{
    api.x = randomRange();
    api.y = 0;
}
```

If you write it like this you don't have to mix stuff up. Try to keep everything seperated, one function does one thing. If you are making a big game try to seperate everything in classes.

Hopefully this fixes the problem and makes it easier for you to finish the game :)